# Centos8: VM broken after moving from VMware ESXi to HyperV

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, hyper-v, grub

I have moved Centos8 VM from ESXi to the HyperV 2019 core (hdd only)
It seems the disks or partitions IDs are broken so it's not staring up properly using default/first Grub menu option.

But it runs with last (rescue) option.

How can I rebuild system config so new UUIDs will be used for boot process?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? You need to be specific. This is currently too vague to offer any sort of answer.

Comment: I assume I have to rebuild configuration somehow so new disks UUID will be used for boot proces... But have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It was not the UUIDs problem.

You have to rebuild the initramfs for your current kernel to suit new VM platform..

In my case command was:

```
dracut -f /boot/initramfs-4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64.img 4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64
```

more:

http://www.cjcheema.com/2019/06/how-to-recover-or-rebuild-initramfs-in-centos-7-linux/